# C# - LINQ - Using column data in the WHERE clause of another LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

This is the database diagram: [database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqtAM.jpg)

So I execute this query:

```
            var query2 = from o in db.Orders
                     join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                     group new { o, od } by o.ShipCountry into oByCountry
                     orderby oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity) descending
                     select new
                     {
                         Country = oByCountry.Key,
                         Total = oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
                     };
```

And I put the result in a datagrid in WPF.

```
GridOverview.ItemsSource = query2;
```

The next thing I want to do is, when I press in that GridOverview on a row, I want to show all customers living in the country of the selected row and the total price of sold items for each customer.
So I define that selected item in var selectedRow.

```
var selectedRow = GridOverview.SelectedItem;

            var query = from c in db.Customers
                    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                    join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                    **where c.Country == selectedRow.**
                    group new {c, o, od} by c.CompanyName into cByName
                    orderby cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity) descending
                    select new
                    {
                        cByName.Key,
                        Total = cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
                    };
```

Now my question is: How can I compare the Country of the selectedRow to C.Country in the where clause??
selectedRow.Country is not working out, but that's probably not how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `where c.Country.key == selectedOrder.Country.key` did you try comparing the key?

Comment: Where do you define the `selectedOrder` variable?

Comment: @shaun, it's wrong. It should be selectedRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work.

Define a new class for your projection.

```
public class CountryTotal
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

The initial query that you assigned to the `ItemSource` had this projection. We can strongly type it as a `CountryTotal` type.

```
select new CountryTotal
{
    Country = oByCountry.Key,
    Total = oByCountry.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
};
```

Your `selectedOrder` below will have the same structure, but the compiler will not know that without some help. To get around that, we use the `as` operator to tell the compiler that we know what we're doing. Lets assert that it is of type `CountryTotal`.

```
var selectedOrder = GridOverview.SelectedItem as CountryTotal;
```

Now we can access the `Country` property and the compiler will not complain.

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
            join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
            where c.Country == selectedOrder.Country // <-----
            group new {c, o, od} by c.CompanyName into cByName
            orderby cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity) descending
            select new
            {
                cByName.Key,
                Total = cByName.Sum(ood => ood.od.UnitPrice * ood.od.Quantity)
            };
```

---

Note: we could also have used the `dynamic` type instead of defining a `CountryTotal` class, but `dynamic` comes with some downsides.

Comment: This was exactly the explanation I needed! I was a bit stuck on the part where I could define a new class. Had been looking up a few things about it, but you explained it very well and I get it now! Thanks so much for the help! and PS: it works!!

Comment: @SaraD You're welcome. And, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, this is the way you're going to compare in LINQ. There are 2 possible ways. Just with the "==" or with ".Equals".

`customers.Where(c => c.country == selectedRow.Country);`

***OR***

`customers.Where(c => c.country.Equals(selectedRow.Country));`

It is possible that you will have to use the "ToLower()"-function or "ToLowerInvariant()"-function. I don't know the context of your project so you wil have so see if it benefits you.